# How Can the Vendor's Address's State Description rather than the Code be displayed in Dynamics AX 2012 R2 CU7?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

When capturing a new Address for a Vendor the State Code is Displayed and not the Description right at the start of the address. This is unmodified **code** in Dynamics AX2012 CU7. This problem manifests everywhere where the Vendor address is referenced.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please review the [SE guidelines on using version-specific tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/135887).  You haven't specified anything anywhere about how the thing you're experiencing is related in any way to one and only one specific version.  Just because you're *using* a specific version, that doesn't mean that your problem only exists in that *one* version.  Further, acronyms are *bad*.  The product name is not "dax."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to wrong setup in the "Address setup" form.

You will have to mark the "Expand" on the state code for the relevant address setups.

After the change you may have to reenter the zip code to get it right.

Comment: Thanks Jan - you've saved us, now working like a charm.